# Android 7 badge counter

Tags: android, counter, badge

I saw in Android's documentation that the counter in the right upper corner is available only on `Android 8 (Oreo)`, but I have a device running `Android 7`, and few apps show the badge counter.

Is there any workaround to achieve this (show the dot counter)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can show badge count on Android 7 as well. There is one famous library for that called [`ShortcutBadger`](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger)

**Usage:**

1. Add mavenCentral to your build script.

   ```
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }
   ```
2. Add dependencies for ShortcutBadger, it's available from maven now.

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar"
   }
   ```
3. Add the codes below:

   ```
   int badgeCount = 1;
   ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, badgeCount); //for 1.1.4+
   ShortcutBadger.with(getApplicationContext()).count(badgeCount); //for 1.1.3
   ```
4. If you want to remove the badge

   ```
   ShortcutBadger.removeCount(context); //for 1.1.4+
   ShortcutBadger.with(getApplicationContext()).remove();  //for 1.1.3

   or

   ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, 0); //for 1.1.4+
   ShortcutBadger.with(getApplicationContext()).count(0); //for 1.1.3
   ```

Here is the [list of supported](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger#supported-launchers) devices

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Downvoter please mention the reason to downvote. Please don't do this bluntly.

Comment: answer accepted! I am not quite familiar with StackOverflow yet, and so far didn't know how to accept :-). Iam what they call "old school" lol
Thanks